# React Jodit Editor text area cursor error

Tags: wysiwyg, react-draft-wysiwyg, jodit

I am currently working on react jodit editor and I want to upload an image to server for that I want to create a button as I use the config option , the editor starts giving errors , the align button automatically getting selected and intercepting my cursor ,

```html
<div className='editor'>
  <JoditEditor ref={editor} onChange={(content)=> setValue(content)} config= {{ autofocus : true , cursorAfterAutofocus: 'end', }}/>
</div>
```

autofocus and cursorAfterAutofocus solved the 50% problem but don't know how to solve the align button problem which is intercepting my cursor again and again ...

Please help me .....